# Neo4j stuck on "running" when executing a query

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to get a Neo4j database server working on my DigitalOcean droplet. The server is containerized (Docker) and works fine locally but when pushing to the server queries cannot be executed and I'm left with the below.

[image: Neo4j stuck on running]

The container itself doesn't display any logs while running and as you can see from the screenshot above, the remote interface is working fine. It's not a permission based error as the mounted volume is having folders written to it when running the container.

The Neo4j.log file is as follows:

```
2017-02-10 17:26:52.753+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2017-02-10 17:26:54.646+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-02-10 17:26:56.480+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2017-02-10 17:27:04.282+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-02-10 17:27:08.763+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://127.0.0.1:7474/
2017-02-10 17:27:09.680+0000 WARN  Failed authentication attempt for 'neo4j' from 127.0.0.1
2017-02-10 17:27:10.503+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2017-02-10 17:27:10.585+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2017-02-10 17:27:10.780+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

Note the failed authentication attempt. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've upgraded my server to 1gb RAM and dropped the heap size to 128mb. My ram usage is well below 100% and there's plenty of swap space but the issue persists.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the UI is connected to the database? (e.g. sometimes there's an issue with Bolt connectivity) Also, have you tried to query with `LIMIT 1` (I have no idea how much data you have, so maybe that doesn't matter).

Comment: I have literally zero data. I suspected it might be due to a lack of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying my answer from Github to increase exposure.

By reading the logs I have a strong guess that you are maxing out the
RAM on your droplet. It seems like your instance had to start
swapping, which will render the database unusable:

```
2017-02-11 15:59:25.918+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] System memory information:
2017-02-11 15:59:25.925+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total Physical memory: 992.82 MB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.925+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free Physical memory: 186.12 MB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.926+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Committed virtual memory: 2.04 GB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.926+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total swap space: 6.84 GB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.926+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free swap space: 6.47 GB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.926+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JVM memory information:
2017-02-11 15:59:25.926+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free  memory: 82.07 MB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.927+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total memory: 128.00 MB
2017-02-11 15:59:25.927+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Max   memory: 128.00 MB
```

I've done some experiments myself with running Neo4j on low memory VPS
instances and I have concluded that it's not viable to run it on a
machine with just 1GB of RAM (which my own Linode instance has). Assuming
that you also want to run anything other than Neo4j on that machine.

The reason is that besides the Java heap and the Neo4j page cache, you
get certain other memory overheads. Lucence will allocate some of its
own off-heap memory (likely at least 32MB). Java itself seems to
require more memory that the configured heap size.

#### Investigating the minimum required memory

To view actual memory usage you can use the `docker stats`
command. Consider for example the following invocation:

```
docker run --rm --name=neo -e NEO4J_AUTH=none -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=8M -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=100M -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j:3.1.1-enterprise
```

Initially you'd suspect this to require about 110MB of RAM right? Well, you'd be wrong:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
a8a86807064b        0.35%               370.1 MiB / 23.44 GiB   1.54%               2.62 kB / 690 B     119 MB / 3.01 MB    43
```

In fact it requires almost 4 times as much as expected. Now let's see what happens if we increase the heap size by 100MB:

```
docker run --rm --name=neo -e NEO4J_AUTH=none -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=8M -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=200M -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j:3.1.1-enterprise
```

Result:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
d92e8ecde4a8        0.43%               497.8 MiB / 23.44 GiB   2.07%               7.12 kB / 59.3 kB   119 MB / 3.01 MB    49
```

Memory usage went up by nearly exactly 100MB. So now, what if we then increase the Neo4j pagecache size to 100MB?

```
docker run --rm --name=neo -e NEO4J_AUTH=none -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=100M -e NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=200M -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j:3.1.1-enterprise
```

Result:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
2474e209f64e        0.38%               472.3 MiB / 23.44 GiB   1.97%               2.62 kB / 690 B     119 MB / 3.01 MB    43
```

No obvious change on startup, so we can assume that this might
potentially allocate 100MB at a later time then. To test this I
applied some load to the db by repeatedly creating the Movie graph
which caused memory to increase ever so slightly:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
77f067c9695c        0.36%               514.2 MiB / 23.44 GiB   2.14%               644 kB / 3.56 MB    120 MB / 4.19 MB    51
```

#### Verdict

Looking at the numbers above, this is a rough idea of Neo4j's memory requirements (with some padding to allow for index memory requirements too):

```
Minimum = 300MB + JavaHeapSize + PageCacheSize
```

Answer (score 0):

How much data is your in database? If you have e.g. 1M users it will return all of them, which will most likely freeze up your browser.

What do you want to achieve?

Make sure to configure heap + page-cache for the docker image and use an external volume for the data directory (not `aufs`).

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/

Comment: I'm starting with an empty volume mount and it's still causing issues. Increasing the RAM seemed to make it work for a short amount of time. I'll let you know if pagefile and heap reductions fix the issue.